# Как узнать, пересекаются ли две ограничивающие сферы объекта?

Tags: javascript, three.js

1. Загружаю в цикле объект `object3D`

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

       //вызов метода, который возвращает контейнер Object3D

   }
   ```
2. внутри цикла соответственно загружаю объект в формате `.fbx`  и далее получаю у каждого объекта ограничивающую сферу. Записываю ее в массив `objects`.

   ```
   let objects;

   this.THREE = THREE;
   const container = new THREE.Object3D();

   const loader = new FBXLoader();

   loader.load(path, object => {
   container.add(object);

   const geo = container.children[0].children[0].geometry;
   geo.computeBoundingSphere();

   objects.push(geo);

   //let center = geo.center();
   //let radius = geo.boundingSphere.radius;
   // проверка пересечения с первой сферой в массиве

   //достаю первый объект из массива
   //нахожу сферу
   const geo2 = objects[0].children[0].children[0].geometry;
   geo2.computeBoundingSphere();

   const isCollision =  geo.intersectsSphere(geo2);
   } )
   ```
3. Проверяю пересечение с первым элементов массива `objects` следующим образом: 
   тут же достаю из `objects geo2` и вызываю метод `intersectsSphere`. (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Sphere.intersectsSphere) Но так не работает. Не получаю значение типа boolean. Где я ошибаюсь?

   ```
   const geo2 = objects[0].children[0].children[0].geometry;
   geo2.computeBoundingSphere();

   const isCollision =  geo.intersectsSphere(geo2);
   ```
4. И как сделать так, чтобы была проверка пересечения сферы текущего объекта со всеми остальными?

Comment: "Но так не работает" - ??

Comment: не получаю значение типа boolen. undefined

Answer (score 1):

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Sphere.intersectsSphere

```
const isCollision = geo.boundingSphere.intersectsSphere(geo2.boundingSphere);
```